# Java Reflection methods hashmap

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap, static-methods

I am trying to add static methods from an existing class to a `HashMap`. All the methods are located in the same class with the following code  :

```
    map.put("x", myClass.class.getMethod("addX"));
    map.put("y", myClass.class.getMethod("addY"));
```

When I run the code I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: package.myClass.addX`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Post the class in question.

Comment: could you post your class, your code is not able to find "addX" method.

Comment: Problem was solbed by using getDeclaredMethod(). Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getDeclaredMethod()` method instead of `getMethod()`.